# pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError : value is not a valid list (type=type_error.list)

Tags: python, api, fastapi, pydantic

New to FastAPI

---

Getting a "value is not a valid list (type=type_error.list)" error

Whenever I try to return  {"posts": post}

```
@router.get('', response_model = List[schemas.PostResponseSchema])
def get_posts(db : Session = Depends(get_db)):
 print(limit)
 posts = db.query(models.Post).all()
 return {"posts" : posts}
```

Although it works if I return posts like this:

```
return posts
```

Here is my response model:

```
class PostResponseSchema(PostBase):
 user_id: int
 id: str
 created_at : datetime
 user : UserResponseSchema

 class Config:
     orm_mode = True
```

And Model:

```
class Post(Base):
 __tablename__ = "posts"
 id =  Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
 title = Column(String, nullable=False)
 content = Column(String, nullable = False)
 published = Column(Boolean, server_default = 'TRUE' , nullable = False)
 created_at = Column(TIMESTAMP(timezone=True), nullable = False, server_default = 
  text('now()'))
 user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("users.id", ondelete = "CASCADE"), nullable = 
  False )

 user = relationship("User")
```

what am I missing here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

your response expects to be the list by this line of code of yours:

```
@router.get('', response_model = List[schemas.PostResponseSchema])
```

but your response `return {"posts" : posts}`  is object.

so you have to return **posts** because it is a list of objects as your response expects. otherwise, if you want to use `return {"posts": posts}` just change `router.get('', response_model = List[schemas.PostResponseSchema])` to `router.get('')` then you will get something like this:

```
{"posts": [......]}
```

inside [] will be a list of posts.

Comment: Don't remove the `response_model=` as this will mean that the documentation no longer contains any information about the response; instead, create a new response model (schema) that has `posts: List[schemas.PostResponseSchema])` as its only property. That way the generated documentation will reflect what the endpoint returns and you still get validation that you're returning the expected format.

Comment: Please upvote Ismaili and accept his answer as he had the actual answer to make it work :-)